# Making two requests with android volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to make two requests with different parameters, response and parameters with volley. Below is my code

```
private void LoadFirst() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        final StringRequest userReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, jsonSubjectListener, errorSubjectListener) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "retrieveFirst");
                return params;
            }

        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(userReq);
    }
}

    private void LoadSecond(final String user_type) {
    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // initialising progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    StringRequest userReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, jsonListener, errorListener) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("tag", "retrieveSecond");

            params.put("user_type", user_type);
            return params;
        }

    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(userReq);
}
```

Then I called these two functions under onActivityCreated of my fragment. But it kept on loading indefinitely. I read something on RequestFuture but  I can't see how it can help me with two different parameters, errorListeners and ResponseListeners. Thanks

Comment: What is `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(userReq);`? Could you post `AppController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take is this. You are calling two methods where each one does this:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

The second time you instantiate a progress dialog on the same reference, the old progress dialog which is still showing is no longer reachable. So it's not that the requests are loading forever. It's just that you can no longer dismiss the first progress dialog. 
I think you just need to instantiate this progress dialog once outside before both methods.

Comment: Thanks @inmyth. That was my mistake. I corrected in and it works.